# ERROR Error: Using removed Babel 5 option:

Tags: vuejs2, babeljs

I am working on Vue project. So far It was working for me.
After I install some packages, it doesn't work.

error is like :

```
ERROR  Error: Using removed Babel 5 option: .modules - Use the corresponding module transform plugin in the `plugins` option. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules
Error: Using removed Babel 5 option: .modules - Use the corresponding module transform plugin in the `plugins` option. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules
    at throwUnknownError (E:\booking_room\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:121:11)
    at Object.keys.forEach.key (E:\booking_room\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:108:5)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validateNested
(E:\booking_room\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:84:21)
    at validate
(E:\booking_room\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:75:10)
    at file 
(E:\booking_room\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:169:34)
    at cachedFunction
(E:\booking_room\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:62:27)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync
(E:\booking_room\node_modules\gensync\index.js:244:28)
    at syn
(E:\booking_room\node_modules\gensync\index.js:84:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! booking_room@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the booking_room@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASSASSIN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T13_19_18_381Z-debug.log
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt'],
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  }
}
```

I am not sure what is the problem. please any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Because I used `modules` that removed Babel 5.

So I replaced `plugins` instead of `modules`.

it works for me.